# How many years does it take for a Quince to fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees

I'm considering getting a Quince (Cydonia Oblonga) tree for my dad for father's day in zone 4A, and was wondering how long after planting it would start producing fruit.

Comment: The only quince I am familiar with is Chaenomeles.  This is the only quince in the Cydonia genus and I need to go check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different plants in the same Family produce quince fruits - Chaenomeles japonica (shrub) and Cydonia oblonga (tree). Unfortunately, neither is hardy outdoors in Zone 4a - even if the plant survives, the likelihood of getting usable fruit is vanishingly small - quince fruits need a long period of ripening in warmth on the bush or tree. Further info below

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1453/#b

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/49917/#b

Information here regarding fruiting requirements

https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/fruit/quinces?type=f

UPDATE

If you want to try anyway, buy a larger specimen of Cydonia oblonga, you may even get fruit the first year, but definitely  by the second, all other things being equal (it survives, it flowers and the flowers don't get caught in cold, the flowers get pollinated, etc).
Chaenomeles are not usually grown for their fruits, they're more an ornamental shrub, but you should start getting fruit (in a year with good weather) within 2-5 years.

Comment: some do survive 4A: http://tcpermaculture.blogspot.com/2011/10/permaculture-plants-quince-tree.html

Answer (score 1):

Most quinces where I live are sold as mature trees. So, if you get a mature quince to transplant then it should fruit normally if looked after.